# Excel Macro crash when running

Tags: excel, vba

In my office, we run some Excel macros from 2 different PCs, and the macros are stored in a shared folder.

We encountered a problem where one of the PCs stopped working with the macro. When we tried to run it manually using F8, it crashed at the first line of code, `Sub GetInfo()`.

I resolved this by removing the first line of code, `Sub GetInfo()`, saving the .xlsm file, and then pasting the line back in. After that, it started working correctly.

Has anyone else encountered this error? What could be the cause, perhaps there is something that corrupts the Excel files.

EDIT 1:
Excel is crashing without any error and this happened on multiple macros while on the other PC they keep working without problems

Comment: Welcome user23560462! Read [The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn your first badge!

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "crash"... does Excel exit without an error message? If not what was the error message?

Comment: Please show more of your code the code that crashes and the code that doesn't.

Comment: I edited the post, the code that crashes is the first line where the Sub declaration is instanced

Comment: Try using [this](https://davetallett26.github.io/SOExcelHW.html) Excel Hello World macro. If it also crashes then something is corrupt on the bad PC and it needs a Windows rebuild. If it doesn't then Excel is corrupted on the bad PC and nneeds a repair or reinstall.

Comment: I have the same issue on multiple different workbooks. My solution is something like yours : Open VB Editor, insert an error on any line, Compile to trigger an Error Message, Correct the error made, save and all is ok for some time... It seems Excel related as collegues report me the same (not tech collegues). It crash with macro as simple as something like "Selection.Value = Now"